# How to communicate between background.js and a web_accessible_resource in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that forces a dialog box onto the screen when the user downloads something in browser.

background.js:

```
chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener((item) => {
    fileID = item.id;
    // Prompt the user to store a backup copy
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: "content.js",
    });
});
```

This code executes a content script that has a dialog box

content.js:

```
var extensionOrigin = "chrome-extension://" + chrome.runtime.id;

if (window.messageSent === undefined) {
    window.messageSent = true;

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        action: "submit the form",
    });
} else {
    if (!location.ancestorOrigins.contains(extensionOrigin)) {
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("frame.html");
        iframe.style.cssText =
            "position:fixed;top:10px;right:10px;display:block;" +
            "width:270px;height:140px;z-index:10000;";
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
}
```

Which renders a dialog that looks like:
[image: web snippet]

as soon a user downloads something in browser.

The problem is that frame.html and frame.js are web_accessible resources. Frame.js is what handles clicking the buttons on the frame.

Notes:

The reason I am injecting a frame rather than using a popup is because I can't figure out a way to force open the popup, which I want to do when the user downloads something in browser.

manifest.json for reference:

```
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "all_frames": true,
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
        }
    ],
    "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"], "persistent": true },
    "web_accessible_resources": ["frame.html", "frame.js"]
```

I am looking for a way for my frame.js to send a message to my background.js.

Comment: The iframe environment is the same as the browser_action popup so you can use chrome.runtime.sendMessage in frame.js.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yep! Works perfectly. Thanks for the help